# Ordering properties in PowerShell classes with inheritance

Tags: powershell, class, properties

When using PowerShell classes with inheritance, is there any way to specify the order of parameters?

In there the inheritance example below, there are two classes (`HttpResponseOK` and `HttpResponseBadRequest`), both of which inherit another class (`HttpResponse`).

In this case, creating an instance of either `HttpResponseOK` and `HttpResponseBadRequest` results in the properties of those objects being listed before the properties of `HttpResponse`. For example -

#### Code

```
$HttpResponseOK = [HttpResponse]::OK("Everything is OK")
$HttpResponseOK | ConvertTo-Json

$HttpResponseBadRequest = [HttpResponse]::BadRequest("Something bad happened")
$HttpResponseBadRequest | ConvertTo-Json
```

#### Response

```
{
  "notification": "Everything is OK",
  "statusCode": 200
}

{
  "exception": "Something bad happened",
  "statusCode": 400
}
```

As you can see, when the response is sent to a user the `statusCode` property appears after the `notification`/`exception` property. Given that `notification`/`exception` will in reality be objects, this means that the `statsCode` is not initially visible in the response.

Is there a way to specify that `statusCode` should go before `notification`/`exception`?

## Inheritance Example

```
Class HttpResponse
{
    [int]$statusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK

    [void]SetStatus(
        [int]$statusCode
    )
    {
        $this.statusCode = $statusCode
    }

    static [HttpResponseOK]OK(
        [object]$notification
    )
    {
        $response = [HttpResponseOK]::new($notification)
        return $response
    }

    static [HttpResponseBadRequest]BadRequest(
        [object]$exception
    )
    {
        $response = [HttpResponseBadRequest]::new($exception)
        return $response
    }
}

Class HttpResponseOK : HttpResponse
{
    [object]$notification

    HttpResponseOK(
        [object]$notification
    )
    {
        $this.SetStatus([HttpStatusCode]::OK)
        $this.notification = $notification
    }
}

Class HttpResponseBadRequest : HttpResponse
{
    [object]$exception

    HttpResponseBadRequest(
        [object]$exception
    )
    {
        $this.SetStatus([HttpStatusCode]::BadRequest)
        $this.exception = $exception
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never done much with classes in Powershell, but if I move the declarations for both `[object]$notification` and `[object]$exception` to the base class `HttpResponse`, The order seems to keep:

```
Class HttpResponse
{
    [int]$statusCode = [System.Net.HttpStatusCode]::OK
    [object]$notification
    [object]$exception

    [void]SetStatus(
        [int]$statusCode
    )
    {
        $this.statusCode = $statusCode
    }

    static [HttpResponseOK]OK(
        [object]$notification
    )
    {
        $response = [HttpResponseOK]::new($notification)
        return $response
    }

    static [HttpResponseBadRequest]BadRequest(
        [object]$exception
    )
    {
        $response = [HttpResponseBadRequest]::new($exception)
        return $response
    }
}

Class HttpResponseOK : HttpResponse
{
    HttpResponseOK(
        [object]$notification
    )
    {
        $this.SetStatus([System.Net.HttpStatusCode]::OK)
        $this.notification = $notification
    }
}

Class HttpResponseBadRequest : HttpResponse
{
    HttpResponseBadRequest(
        [object]$exception
    )
    {
        $this.SetStatus([System.Net.HttpStatusCode]::BadRequest)
        $this.exception = $exception
    }
}

$HttpResponseOK = [HttpResponse]::OK("Everything is OK")
$HttpResponseOK | ConvertTo-Json

$HttpResponseBadRequest = [HttpResponse]::BadRequest("Something bad happened")
$HttpResponseBadRequest | ConvertTo-Json
```

Output:

> ```
> {
>     "statusCode":  200,
>     "notification":  "Everything is OK",
>     "exception":  null
> }
> {
>     "statusCode":  400,
>     "notification":  null,
>     "exception":  "Something bad happened"
> }
> ```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I did consider using one class initially, but the issue was that I had a `null` value for either `notification` or `exception`. Unfortunately the same issue exists with your suggestion.